# Recurrence relation for the probability of k succeses out of n Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, combinations

If we flip a **biased** coin $n$ times, what is the probability of getting $k$ heads?

Let the $p_{nk}$ denote the probability of $k$ heads over $n$ coin flips, then

$$p_{nk} = \frac{(\text{# of outcomes containing $k$ heads)}}{\text{total outcomes}} = \frac{n\choose k}{2^n}$$

**Question:** *How would we express $p_{nk}$ as a recurrence relation?*

I tried deriving it from the recurrence relation of the count as follows:

$P_{nk}$ is the number of ways of obtaining $k$ heads over $n$ tosses. There are 2 ways of ending up with $k$ tosses by the $n$-th toss:

1. Getting $k-1$ heads on the previous $(n-1)$ tosses (this case is denoted $P_{(n-1)(k-1)}$) and then another head on the $n$-th toss.
2. Getting $k$ heads on the previous $(n-1)$ tosses (denoted $P_{(n-1)k}$) and a tail on the n-th toss.

Adding the counts for these two scenarios, we get $P_{nk} = P_{(n-1)(k-1)} + P_{(n-1)k}$.

Since $p_{nk} = \frac{P_{nk}}{2^n}$, I tried subbing in $P_{nk} = p_{nk}*2^n$, but this gives me the recurrence for an *unbiased* coin (as implied by the "$1/2$" coefficients I think):

$$\begin{align*} p_{nk}*2^n &= p_{(n-1)(k-1)}*2^{n-1} + p_{(n-1)k}*2^{n-1} \\ p_{nk} &= \frac{1}{2}p_{(n-1)(k-1)} + \frac{1}{2}p_{(n-1)k} \end{align*}$$

My attempt seems to have implicitly assumed that the coin is unbiased, why is this?

Since our coin is biased, the correct answer should be $p_{nk} = pp_{(n-1)(k-1)} + qp_{(n-1)k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is when you write $p_{nk}=\frac{P_{nk}}{2^n}$. This is only true when $p=1/2$. The correct relation is $p_{n,k}=P_{nk}\,p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, but in the spirit of the problem, we do not know this yet.

You need to directly find a recurrence for $p_{nk}$, without going through $P_{nk}$. To do this, condition on the last coin tossed. Letting $H$ be the event that the last coin is heads, and $T$ be the event it is tails, then using the law of total probability,
$$
p_{n,k}=P(\text{$k$ heads}\mid H)P(H)+P(\text{$k$ heads}\mid T)P(T)
$$
Now, given that the last coin is heads, the event $\{\text{$k$ heads}\}$ occurs if and only if there are $k-1$ heads among the first $n-1$ coins, so $\dots$

Comment: +1: nicely written